# Nightmare trying to solve a git conflict on a Xcode project

Tags: git, xcode

I am new to git. I know the basic stuff and very badly.

A few days ago I have branched from a master remote to create a branch called `coreData`.

Other stuff have been merged into the remote master. So, the remote master is ahead of the master I have used to branch.

Now I have `coreData` finished. I want to open a pull request on that, so it can be merged into the master.

I have tried the little I know to solve that.

What I have did so far.

Make my local master equal to remote master

- git checkout master
- git pull

then

- git checkout coreData
- git rebase master

also tried

- git checkout coreData
- git merge master

in both cases I solved all conflicts, but the results are not what they should be.

I think my big problem is the `.xcodeproj`.

This is something I do not understand for the `xcodeproj`. See the image below:

[image]

This conflict is impossible. It tells me that one line is replacing all the blue block. It is impossible. In cases like that I accept both, but the final `xcodeproj` becomes corrupt or incorrect.

Is there a way to solve that? If you need more info, please ask and I'll post.

Comment: To me it looks like someone changed `xcodeproj` and pushed it to master. When you are rebasing your newly pulled master, it's normal to get conflicts about this. If you don't know why `xcodeproj` changed, then maybe it's better to ask the person who introduced the changes and figure out if they are worth saving or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak specifically to xcode project files, however, auto generated project files are often one of the most difficult types of (text-based) files to resolve using merge conflict functionality. Sometimes, when both sides have just added new things, it is as easy as accepting both sides. Unfortunately, as you are witnessing, that doesn't always work. Essentially you are trying to manually edit a file that is auto-generated, and sometimes the file has expectations and/or ordering rules that you may not be able to manually re-create without knowing the exact details of how the file is generated.

When this sort of thing happens to me, I typically take a stab at it, and then I create a new branch off of the updated target branch, re-do just my project level changes, and take a look at the newly created project file. You may be able to simply copy that version of the project file into your other (almost-working) branch and be good to go. Comparing them in this way may also help pinpoint where your merge went wrong. Oftentimes it's a missing or incorrect GUID somewhere.

**Side note:** you can save a few steps in your workflow by skipping checking out `master`. Instead, with your branch checked out, you can just:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

You can even delete your local copy of `master`, and from now on, create new branches off of `origin/master`, and use the same when rebasing or merging. Every time you `git fetch` you'll update your copy of `origin/master`.

Comment: I will try that. THANKS!